# unicode findall python

Tags: python, regex

I have a working pattern for english language but for my native language is not working and it give me headaches. First of all i have opened many question about encoding, and i know that i underestimated it, it was a big problem. I spent some time reading about it, and the problem is still there. So now i am facing a regular expression utf problem. So the pattern is:

```
exactMatch = re.compile(r"([^\.]*\bтурција\b[^\.]*)\.", re.UNICODE)
print exactMatch.pattern
result= exactMatch.findall("турција е на врвот од индустријата. турција е на врвот од индустријата.")
```

It works for english language. It function is to give me all sentences in a paragraph. So any suggestions?

I have also tried with encode and decode but noting happens except encoding error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this will work:

```
exactMatch = re.compile(ur"([^\.]*\bтурција\b[^\.]*)\.", re.UNICODE)
print exactMatch.pattern
result= exactMatch.findall(u"турција е на врвот од индустријата. турција е на врвот од индустријата.")
```

if you use unicode, then **use** unicode.

Comment: what error do you get? it works for me. also, make sure your file has the [correct encoding set](http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html).